# Bad image quality for website

Tags: web, photoshop, image-resizing, image-quality

I’m quite new to creating responsive websites and I’m finding it difficult to put a good quality image in my website page.

I have a 4000x4000px image I want to put on the homepage, and I’m trying to downscale it to a more reasonable 1000x1000px (I need it to be big and in good quality).

The problem is that every time I try to resize it, the quality becomes very bad.

These are the things I did try to resize it in Photoshop:

- resize it down with automatic resample
- resize it down with Bicubic sharpener resample
- resize it down with no resample
- resize it down using only drag and drop

Had no luck with any of these methods.
Any help? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to downscale image or export graphics for web with Photoshop - is [**Save For Web And Devices**](http://blogs.adobe.com/crawlspace/2015/06/save-for-web-in-photoshop-cc-2015.html) *(it's legacy option, but still available in file > export)* or [**Export As**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/export-image-web.html) option. There you'll be able to select the quality, format and change the size of your graphic.

Anyway, if you want to add hi-res images *(to use it for retina displays for example)* to your website, the best way to implement it is to use srcset:
[**responsive images**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)

Good luck :)